# How to change this table so that it fits in the available text block?

Tags: tables, adjustbox

I'm trying to insert a table. If I scale the table via `\resizbox`, the glyphs are not readable as they are too small. How do I fit it so the contents are easily readable?

```
\begin{table}[]
\small\addtolength{\tabcolsep}{-4pt}
\caption{Number of Projects in each Rank}
\label{my-label}
\resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{lllllllll}
 & \multicolumn{2}{l}{{\bf 2012-13}} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{{\bf 2013-14}} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{{\bf 2014-15}} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{{\bf Cumulative}} \\
{\bf Ranking Criteria} & Allocations  (Rs. Million) & No. of Projects & Allocations  (Rs. Million) & No. of Projects & Allocations         (Rs. Million) & No. of Projects & Allocations       (Rs. Million) & No. of Projects \\
{\bf 1} & 422 & 15 & 1317 & 24 & 1941 & 9 & 3680 & 48 \\
{\bf 2} & 2237 & 28 & 1348 & 37 & 5271 & 18 & 8856 & 83 \\
{\bf 3} & 1010 & 7 & 1393 & 22 & 2666 & 23 & 5069 & 52 \\
{\bf 4} & 1215 & 2 & 386 & 2 & 110.46 & 2 & 1711 & 6
\end{tabular}
}
\end{table}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: The columns are too wide, try to use wrapping of the column headings with `p{0.75in}` instead of `l` type, for example. And `\bf` is deprecated. Use `\textbf{1}` etc. instead in the first column

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you

- use an environment, such as `tabularx`, along with its associated `X` column type instead of the basic `tabular` environment. That way, you can get automatic line wrapping
- modify the basic `X` column type to employ ragged-right typesetting while allowing hyphenation
- insert `\hspace{0pt}` directives as needed to allow hyphenation of the first word in each cell (Aside: This measure isn't necessary if you use LuaLaTeX to compile your document)
- use the line-drawing commands of the `booktabs` package to organize visually the material in the table's headers.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,caption,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\small
\addtolength{\tabcolsep}{-3pt}
\caption{Number of projects in each rank} \label{my-label}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{*{9}{L}}
\toprule
 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{2012--13}}
 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{2013--14}}
 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{2014--15}}
 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Cumulative}} \\
 \cmidrule(r){2-3} \cmidrule(r){4-5} \cmidrule(r){6-7} \cmidrule{8-9} 
\textbf{\hspace{0pt}Ranking Criteria}
& \hspace{0pt}Allocations  (Rs.\ Million) & No.\ of Projects 
& \hspace{0pt}Allocations  (Rs.\ Million) & No.\ of Projects 
& \hspace{0pt}Allocations  (Rs.\ Million) & No.\ of Projects 
& \hspace{0pt}Allocations  (Rs.\ Million) & No.\ of Projects \\
\midrule
\textbf{1} & 422 & 15 & 1317 & 24 & 1941 & 9 & 3680 & 48 \\
\textbf{2} & 2237 & 28 & 1348 & 37 & 5271 & 18 & 8856 & 83 \\
\textbf{3} & 1010 & 7 & 1393 & 22 & 2666 & 23 & 5069 & 52 \\
\textbf{4} & 1215 & 2 & 386 & 2 & 110.46 & 2 & 1711 & 6\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Rather than resizing for accommodating large headers, I believe it's better to add a legend at the bottom of the table.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx,caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering

\caption{Number of Projects in each Rank}
\label{my-label}

\begin{tabular}{
 l
 S[table-format=4.0]S[table-format=2.0]
 S[table-format=4.0]S[table-format=2.0]
 S[table-format=4.2]S[table-format=2.0]
 S[table-format=4.0]S[table-format=2.0]
}
\toprule
{\bfseries RC}
 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\bfseries 2012-13}
 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\bfseries 2013-14}
 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\bfseries 2014-15}
 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\bfseries Cumulative}
\\
\cmidrule(lr){2-3}
\cmidrule(lr){4-5}
\cmidrule(lr){6-7}
\cmidrule(lr){8-9}
 & {A} & {NP} & {A} & {NP} & {A} & {NP} & {A} & {NP}
\\
\midrule
\textbf{1} &  422 & 15 & 1317 & 24 & 1941    &  9 & 3680 & 48 \\
\textbf{2} & 2237 & 28 & 1348 & 37 & 5271    & 18 & 8856 & 83 \\
\textbf{3} & 1010 &  7 & 1393 & 22 & 2666    & 23 & 5069 & 52 \\
\textbf{4} & 1215 &  2 &  386 &  2 &  110.46 &  2 & 1711 &  6 \\
\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
\multicolumn{9}{@{}l@{}}{\small RC stands for ``Ranking Criteria''} \\
\multicolumn{9}{@{}l@{}}{\small A stands for ``Allocations (Rs.\ Million)''} \\
\multicolumn{9}{@{}l@{}}{\small NP stands for ``Number of Projects''}
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]